# Accidentally created a branch called --track, and now I can't delete it

Tags: git, branch, git-track

So I ran this command:

```
git checkout -b --track origin/RB_1.4.5
```

I thought that it would create a local branch by the same name and set it up to track the remote branch, but instead it created a branch called --track.  I could have sworn that omitting the local branch name will normally cause it to assume you want the same name as the remote branch, but I guess this wasn't the case.

Now running:

```
git branch
```

gives me:

```
* --track
  master
```

I've tried checking out master and then running:

```
git branch -D --track  (as well as "--track")
```

but that doesn't do anything (no errors or anything).

I tried removing the corresponding lines in .git/config, but still no dice.

How can I remove that branch?  Also, in the future, is there a way to do what I wanted and still not have to re-type the local branch name?

Comment: I just tried it with the options reversed, and this time it created a local branch from master called "origin/RB_1.4.5".  Deleting it wasn't a problem however.  I guess you're just forced to re-type the local branch name :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
git branch -D -- --track
```

Should tell git to ignore dashes after `--`